# Phonegap Windows Phone gap space bottom

Tags: css, cordova, windows-phone

I developp with phonegap and I have got a problem with the style.

I just want to place a footer at the bottom.

Here is my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>    
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
    <title>Hello World</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova-2.6.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
</head>
<body id="page">        
    <div id="bottom">
        <p>Bonjour</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my css

```
#bottom {
position:fixed;
width: 100%;
bottom: 0px;
background-color: #f00;
}
body {
min-height: 533px;
height : 100%;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}
```

And I've got this

[Result on the phone](http://hpics.li/e42f19f)

How can I solve this, or anyone meet the same problem?

Thanks !

Comment: Is it only on windows phone ? Maybe its a special gap for windows buttons

Comment: Yes it's only on windows phone. We already try on iphone and android and it's work fine.

Comment: @ChristopheSophy i wish i could upvote that comment...

Comment: that being said, did you try position absolute bottom 0 just to see if it was a quirk w/ position fixed? also try getting rid of the "min height" as that could be the issue also apply height width 100 percent padding margin 0 to html you never know with windows..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing, is that to position fixed does not work on IE.

To fix this, I add to include jquery on my project and change the position to absolute

```
#bottom {
position:absolute;
width: 100%;
bottom: 0px;
background-color: #f00;        
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
left: 0px;
}
```

and my index.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />

    <title>Hello World</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/latest/jquery.mobile.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/latest/jquery.mobile.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova-2.6.0.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>

</head>
<body>  
    <div id="bottom">
        <p>Bonjour</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And now it's working

Answer (score 0):

Check the styles, make sure there aren't any other styles that are being automatically added.  The one thing to check in particular is the style for the `<p>`  Try setting the margin and padding both to 0.