# Windows Phone screen height in PhoneGap app not 100%

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, cordova

I'm developing a Windows Phone app using PhoneGap/Cordova (though, I believe the problem I'm having makes the fact that it's PhoneGap irrelevant).
No matter what I seem to do, the  tag of my html pages doesn't fill the screen vertically.
It looks fine when running the pages in Chrome or even IE
Here is what it looks like on the Emulator, I added a blue border to the  tag in the .css for emphasis of what's going on:

[image]

Here's the css for the body:

```
  body{
    border: 1px blue solid;

}

html, body{
    height:100%;
    min-height:100%
}
```

here's the footers css:

```
div.navbar_table_container {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;   
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    background-image:url(images/bottom-nav.png);
    background-size:100% 100%;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    text-align: center;
}
```

and, as it may be important, here's the xaml file:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage 
    x:Class="CordovaWP8_2_7_01.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d" FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
    FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
    Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
    Background="White"
    SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"
    shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True" d:DesignHeight="820" d:DesignWidth="480" 
    xmlns:my="clr-namespace:WPCordovaClassLib">
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <my:CordovaView HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                   Margin="0,0,0,0"  
                   x:Name="CordovaView" 
                   VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
        <Image Source="SplashScreenImage.jpg"
          x:Name="SplashImage"
          VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
            <Image.Projection>
                <PlaneProjection x:Name="SplashProjector"  CenterOfRotationX="0"/>
            </Image.Projection>
        </Image>
    </Grid>

</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

an important note is that it works the way I want it to in Chrome, IE, and when I run it as an android app.

The closest question to mine that I could find was 
[Phonegap Windows Phone gap space bottom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16355253/phonegap-windows-phone-gap-space-bottom)
but the answer there doesn't help me.

I've noticed recently that when I run the same code off of a web server and access it using IE on a windows phone, it looks fine. However, I did notice that whenever an Alert was shows on the phone, the address bar of IE goes away and leaves behind the EXACT same gap from the bottom of the web content to the bottom of the phone as the native app is always showing.

So, that leads me to believe that, even though it's an "app", if it's running html and javascript, the phone leaves space for an address bar, even though it's never used.

Any help or insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I've taken the www folder from this project and placed it in an Eclipse android PhoneGap project and ran it on the Android emulators. It looks fine there. So I'm still unsure as to why it's not correct on the widows phone.

Comment: I've taken the www folder and uploaded to my web server and tried to navigate to it using using IE on a windows phone. Doing that, it formats correctly. So this really has something to do with the way windows phone handles html apps I'm guessing. 

As a "true webpage" it looks fine, but when compiled as an app, it has the bottom gap issue.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I tried using device-height in the viewport meta tag, however I learned that IE doesn't support that tag. Then after my 100,000 google search, I found [this page](http://trentwalton.com/2013/01/16/windows-phone-8-viewport-fix/).

After adding this to my CSS:

```
@viewport{height:device-height}
@viewport{width:device-width}
@-ms-viewport{height:device-height}
@-ms-viewport{width:device-width}
```

and adding this to a JavaScript file that hits all of my pages:

```
if (navigator.userAgent.match(/IEMobile\/10\.0/)) {
    var msViewportStyle = document.createElement("style");

    msViewportStyle.appendChild(
        document.createTextNode(
            "@-ms-viewport{width:auto!important}"
        )
    );

    msViewportStyle.appendChild(
        document.createTextNode(
            "@-ms-viewport{height:device-height!important}"
        )
    );

    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(msViewportStyle);
}
```

Then my 100% body height started acting the way that I would expect it to.

Comment: Hi Sharpleaf, in CSS, the ms viewport width is set to device-width, then why do we need to set it again with a different value(auto??) in the js code???? It makes me confused.....

Comment: Careful, if you put the CSS notations, you will loose CSS-density declarations (your device will declare a screen pixel / CSS pixel ratio of 1, instead of 2 or 3 on high density screens, which may result in very small layouts). I believe that the device-width CSS and then the JS fix with auto could be a little "hack" to fix the screen size detected by IEmobile. But sharpleaf can certainly give us more insights on that JS

Answer (score 3):

In your `MainPage.xaml` file,  change

```
shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True"
```

to

```
shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="False"
```

Comment: That did it for me after I added the other answer.

Answer (score 1):

it seems that the key is width property in -ms-viewport, so a simpler solution would be:

```
// put this in body or after body as it uses document.body.offsetWidth.
if (/IEMobile\/10\.0/.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
    document.write('<style>@-ms-viewport { width: ' + document.body.offsetWidth + 'px; }</style>');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The overflow is a weird IE10 WebBrowser control thing. If you change the background color of the body you will see that both above and below your div are the background color.

Here is a simple workaround:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    var div = document.querySelector(".navbar_table_container");
    div.style.top = (div.offsetTop + div.offsetHeight + 4) + "px";
});
```