# Bad imaging using Google maps on Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: google-maps, cordova, windows-phone-8

I'm using Google maps in my Phonegap project for WP8.1 and Android.
On Android everything works fine but on WP, I have problem with imaging.
When I move with map, the map is broken and confusing - an example is in
the images below.

I use Microsoft 535 device(if this is relevant for the solution).

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Difficult to say without code.

But maybe it has something to do with the layout.
The Map should be inside of a layout that set it's width and height according to the phone size. If the layout container is too small, the map and all the other UI might seem distorted.

Internet Explorer doesn't support the device-height in the viewport meta tag.[(1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16705223/windows-phone-screen-height-in-phonegap-app-not-100/17071623#17071623)

Or check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17071623/4782402) out!

Comment: thx for answer ... but i solved my problem by using Bing maps... And now works everithing well (of course).

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem.
I solved it by retargeting my project from WP 8.0 to WP 8.1
https://i.stack.imgur.com/MecCg.png

[This](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-us/6fd5b4ed-488d-41d8-98ff-467b101d2bde/google-maps-bug-when-using-the-webbrowser-control/) is the same problem